# Can I add an organization-level gcp Custom Role to a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a [Custom Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) in a Google Cloud organization, then apply that group to one of that organization's projects.  However, this doesn't seem to work:

```sh
$ gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding \
      --member="group:data.viewer@example.com" \ 
      --role="roles/viewer" "my-project"
ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Group data.viewer@example.com does not exist.
```

Here is the organizational-level role I'm trying to assign:

```sh
$ gcloud iam roles describe data.viewer --organization 1234567
description: Can View Analytics
etag: ...
name: organizations/1234567/roles/data.viewer
stage: ALPHA
title: Data Viewer
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) seems open to interpretation:

```
Custom roles can only be used to grant permissions in policies for the same project or organization that owns the roles or resources under them. You cannot grant custom roles from one project or organization on a resource owned by a different project or organization.
```

Does that mean that my custom role *can* or *cannot* be used in a project within that organization?

I'm also wondering if this is not the correct way to group users together and give them permissions to various projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above error, it seems that Group data.viewer@example.com does not exist.
Can you make sure that this group does exist and owned by the same organization?

Comment: This is my misunderstanding of Google Groups. My mental paradigm was that a "Google Group", being the usenet / dejanews descendant, is for managed mailing lists (and aliases), and a gcp permission "group" was something totally different.  Obviously that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, as per the cloud documentation [1],  “You cannot create custom roles at the folder level. Custom roles can only be used to grant permissions in policies for the same project or organization that owns the roles or resources under them. You cannot grant custom roles from one project or organization on a resource owned by a different project or organization.” Please refer to the blue colored note on that page.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles#basic_concepts

Comment: I saw that but I interpreted (incorrectly) as that an organization role would be available to a project within that organization.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You need to specify the role in the project as:

organizations/1234567/roles/data.viewer